Case join query from 2 different tables
I want to get Count and Average values from two different tables as one final output.
I use case statements to get the records fusioned, but which doesn't work.
The team Pole_B is present in both tables and i want to get the values of both tables in the same line.
What i get actually wrong is :
team_a  team_b  pts_a   pts_b   avg_c   pts_d   pts_e   avg_f
Pole_A  Pole_B      12      12      3.7     12      12  3.0 
Pole_A  Pole_C      12      12      3.7     12      12  3.0
Pole_A  Pole_D      12      12      3.7     12      12  3.8
Pole_B  Pole_B      16      16      2.8     16      16  3.0
Pole_B  Pole_C      16      16      2.8     16      16  3.0
Pole_B  Pole_D      16      16      2.8     16      16  3.8

What i want to get is:
team_ab pts_a   pts_b   avg_c   pts_d   pts_e   avg_f
Pole_A      3       3       3,7     0       0   0
Pole_B      4       4       2,8     4       4   3,0
Pole_C      0       0       0       4       4   3,0
Pole_D      0       0       0       4       4   3,8

Here is my query :
SELECT a.team_a, b.team_b,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN a.pts_a !=99 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS pts_a,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN a.pts_b !=99 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS pts_b,
   ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN a.avg_c IN(1,2,3,4,5) THEN avg_c END),1) AS avg_c, 
   COUNT(CASE WHEN b.pts_d !=99 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS pts_d,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN b.pts_e !=99 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS pts_e,
   ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN b.avg_f IN(1,2,3,4,5) THEN avg_f END),1) AS avg_f
FROM tbla a
LEFT JOIN tblb b ON a.week_a = b.week_b
GROUP BY team_a, team_b
ORDER BY team_a ASC;

I have create a fiddle if somebody can take a look inside.
Here is my Sql Fiddle
Thanks in advance

I don't understand your real world problem and the data structure, the two tables, also seems strange to me. I suspect the database modelling is poor. It is also strange that you did not want to count the 99 in your query, but this is the case in the example result.
Nevertheless, I can produce the result you want.
Here it is.
WITH all_data(team, pts_a, pts_b, avg_c, pts_d, pts_e, avg_f, week) AS (
                         SELECT team_a, pts_a, pts_b, avg_c, null, null, null, week_a
                         FROM
                             tbla
                         UNION ALL
                         SELECT team_b, null, null, null, pts_d, pts_e, avg_f, week_b
                         FROM
                             tblb
                     )
     SELECT team,
         COUNT(pts_a) AS pts_a,
         COUNT(pts_b) AS pts_b,
         COALESCE(ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN avg_c IN(1,2,3,4,5) THEN avg_c END),1), 0) AS avg_c,
         COUNT(pts_d) AS pts_d,
         COUNT(pts_e) AS pts_e,
         COALESCE(ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN avg_f IN(1,2,3,4,5) THEN avg_f END),1), 0) AS avg_f,
         week
     FROM all_data
     GROUP BY team, week
     ORDER BY team;

I have added the week to the output.
Pole_A  3   3   3.7 0   0   0   7
Pole_B  4   4   2.8 4   4   3   7
Pole_C  0   0   0   4   4   3   7
Pole_D  0   0   0   4   4   3.8 7

